# Script to auto refresh filter in cell D3

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to automate a script that will auto update the filter in cell D3 when an employee changes shift from employee sheet. Unless there is a better way to filter the column "D".
This is just a template, my real google sheet has about 200 employees and around 150 tabs function/weekday.

I manage to created an action button, but i would have to manually update it without knowing if an employee changed shift on the employee sheet, "shift")
I'v been searching for months on the web without any result.

Thank you in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NWncSMxv0FUWrlHC8WU-ELGrfJcSvt0xjI7B7RwFyZQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trigger [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) to check if you are changing any value in D3, and then change the filter of each sheet. Keep in mind this would only trigger if the change is made manually, not by a script or function:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet_name = sheet.getName();

  //Run only if the Column C from 1 to x is edited in Sheet Employees
  if (sheet_name == 'Employee' && e.range.getColumn() == 3 && e.range.getRow() > 1){

    var new_value = e.value;
    var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = sprsheet.getSheets();

    for (var i = 1; i < sheets.length; i++){

      var filter = sheets[i].getFilter();
      var values = ['WD','WE','WN']; //Values of the filter

      switch(new_value){

        case values[0]:              
          var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
          .setVisibleValues([values[0]])
          .setHiddenValues([values[1], values[2]]);
          break;
        case values[1]:
          var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
          .setVisibleValues([values[1]])
          .setHiddenValues([values[0], values[2]]);
          break;
        case values[2]:
          var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
            .setVisibleValues([values[2]])
          .setHiddenValues([values[0], values[1]]);
          break;
      }

        filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(4, filterCriteria);

    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to solve this.

**REFERENCES:**

- [FilterCriteriaBuilder class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#build)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)